# Analysis of a Holomorphic function $f$ given $1 \geq |f '(z)|$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Since $f$ is holomorphic we can use Cauchy's inequality.

Thus for $n = 1$ we have $ |f'(z)|\leq \frac{M}{R} $ where is $M$ is the max value of $|f(z)|$ and $R$ is the radius of a random region. We also know that $|f'(z)|\leq 1 $.

**My question is :** Can we conclude that $M = R$, therefore $|f(z)|\leq R$ and due to Liouville's theorem that $f$ is constant ?

**Edit:** $f:\mathbb{C} \mapsto \mathbb{C}$ and $|f'(z)|\leq 1 $ for every $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$.
**Edit 2:** As Per Manne pointed out correctly we can't assume $f$ is constant. Can we make any conclusions about the geometry of $f(z)$ though ?

Comment: There are a lot of things missing. What are the assumptions on $f$ precisely?

Comment: yeah sorry , check the edit.

Comment: There is an obvious counterexample: The function $f(z)=z$ satisfies your conditions and is not constant.

Comment: you are right. So what's safe to conclude about f ?

Comment: If $f$ is entire, so is $f'$. You assumed it's bounded, therefore Liouville applies to $f'$.

Comment: correct. that leads to the same conclusion with Per Manne's answer.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*: Try to show that the function $$g(z)={f(z)-f(0) \over z}$$ is a bounded holomorphic function with a removable singularity at the origin.

Comment: thanks !! much appreciated :D